# How to analyze esp8266 static memory consumption

Tags: memory-management, esp8266

If In my esp8266 project, i have added a lot of stuff and many libraries going carelessly. And now i am in need of some more free ram. I want to analyze which objects are consuming more memory. Is there any tool or is it possible to do with gdb ? To analyze/visualize the static memory consumption ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I tried GDB and other tools, but nothing seemed easy and good.
Then i stumbled onto platformio inspect.
Go to Platformio Home and click inspect in sidebar. It gives static analysis of the binary.
Works awesome.